# output not a trimmed value and causing the output error

Tags: powershell

I have written few powershell command to perform some auditing on HyperV Clusters. The command works fine, But can anyone help me to trim the output, so that I can collect what I need ?

```
##Audit-CreatingDC
$AuditDC = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\cluster\resources -recurse | get-itemproperty -name CreatingDC  -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'}| ft CreatingDC,PSComputerName

####Audit-iSCSI
#Show which hosts are not communicating to the storage with the ‘-s’ and where there are duplicated targets:
$AuditISCSI = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName { get-iscsisession } | FT PSComputerName, InitiatorPortalAddress, IsConnected -autosize

######Discover checkdsk errors - "Scan Needed".  Execute using txt of one node from each cluster.
$AuditCHKDSK = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName { get-volume | Where-Object –FilterScript { $_.HealthStatus -eq "Scan Needed" }} | FT PSComputerName, FileSystem, HealthStatus -autosize
```

And the output for each is below

```
CreatingDC                 PSComputerName                                                                      
----------                 --------------                                                                      
\\dc-sc-02.oim.corp.com    slcoc037                                                                            



PSComputerName InitiatorPortalAddress IsConnected
-------------- ---------------------- -----------
slcoc037       10.214.61.107                 True



PSComputerName FileSystem HealthStatus
-------------- ---------- ------------
slcoc037       CSVFS                 1
```

But I need the output for above in this format

```
\\dc-sc-02.oim.corp.com

10.241.81.107

CSVFS                 1
```

Can anyone help me to trim these 3 commands ?

Comment: $AuditDC.CreatingDC, $AuditISCSI.Initia.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably already know that almost all powershell outputs are objects. Objects have properties. Displaying a particular property would use the syntax `$Object.Propertyname`. In your case, `CreatingDC` is a property of the `$AuditDC` Variable object. Applying that logic, all you need to do is, display it like this:

```
$AuditDC.CreatingDC
$AuditISCSI.InitiatorPortalAddress
$AuditCHKDSK.FileSystem
```

Comment: I tried this and I am not getting any output for this

Comment: I dd not notice this earlier. Also change the `FT` on each line to `Select-Object`.